# Using github on my project that uses NuGet

Tags: .net, git, github, nuget

I'm creating an open-source .net web development framework called "ExpressForms".  I just now uploaded the project to github: https://github.com/DanielLangdon/ExpressForms.

I used NuGet to set up my code to run with the latest versions of ASP.net MVC and Entity Framework; these are saved in a "packages" directory below the solution.  I can see that by default, git ignores this directory when uploading my project to github.

When I download the project from github to another directory, this directory is missing and the solution won't build.

What do I need to do to make it so that another developer can easily download my code from github and build it right away without any fuss?

I am still new to git, so it's likely I'm missing something basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to [enable NuGet package restore in your newly downloaded solution](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

When using NuGet with GitHub, GitHub ignores the files under the `packages` directory because it's usually not a good idea to commit binary files (like DLL libraries) to Git, because it causes Git repos to become bloated in size over time because they have to keep each version of a binary in the repo history forever (unless you go back and erase them with `git filter-branch`).

As a workaround, NuGet was designed with "package restore", which specifies any dependencies your solution may have in a text xml file, which is easily and efficiently versioned by Git. So only that file should be committed to Git.

When you enable package restore and build your solution, NuGet will check the config file and automatically download any dependencies specified in it.