# What's a good filepath to force .gitignore not to ignore dlls in package folders?

Tags: git, gitignore

So I've got this path in my .gitignore file: `!packages/*/lib/*/*.dll` which will stop git ignoring anything that has specific versions of the dll for specific versions of .NET. However, things like Elmah don't have different versions (the path for the current version of Elmah is something like `packages\elmah.corelibrary.1.2.2\lib\Elmah.dll`).

I know that if I add `!packages/*/lib/*.dll` it will catch things like this, but I'd rather not add a new path for each one that is slightly different.

I've tried adding `!packages/*/lib/**/*.dll` but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Git are you using? `**` was [only available after version 1.8.2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.2/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt#L85-88).

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid versioning binary files in Git

***Why don't you want to ignore DLLs, period?*** ***Git isn't well-suited for versioning binary files***, because it has to keep entire copies of each version every time they change, which causes the repos to become larger in size over time, which makes them harder to clone, and probably slows down other Git operations too.

In addition, remote repo hosts like GitHub may have a limit on how big your repo can be. [GitHub's current limit is 1 Gigabyte](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota) (emphasis mine):

> ***For best performance, we recommend repositories be kept under 1GB each. This limit is easy to stay within if large files (typically, binaries) are kept out of the repository***. If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive a polite email from support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down under 1GB.

### Try to use NuGet Package Restore instead

**[Elmah is available via a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ELMAH)**. **Is using [NuGet package restore not an option for you](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages)?** If you enable it, you can just version the xml config file that specifies which version of Elmah to use, and your project will download it during build if you don't have it already.

See also [Using github on my project that uses NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107210/using-github-on-my-project-that-uses-nuget/18107301#18107301).

### Regarding .gitignore **

The `**` syntax was only [made available after Git version 1.8.2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.2/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt#L85-88), so if you're using an earlier version of Git, that might be why it's not working. You can check your version by running `git --version`.

Comment: A few things: 1. Not using Github, we're using Stash (Atlassian's version of Github Enterprise). 2. I've had bad experiences with nuget package restore in the past. 3. We use quite a few third party dlls that aren't available via nuget. Admittedly these won't be in the packages folder but an overall "don't put dlls in git" isn't going to help much.

Comment: @PiersKarsenbarg if you upgrade your DLL libraries often, it's in your best interest to avoid versioning them in Git, as much as possible. If that's a concern to you, it would help if you could describe what our problems with NuGet package restore have been in the past. Okay, wait, actually, there's another solution, you could go ahead and version them, but eventually you might need to delete obsolete ones from the repo using `filter-branch`. However, that's not a task to take lightly, since it does destroy data, and rewrite your entire history of course.

Comment: We hardly ever upgrade unless we have. There was an issue with .gitignore where some of the dlls from the packages folder weren't being saved as part of the snapshot. I just want to make sure this doesn't happen again.

Answer (score -1):

A good answer is to look at your global gitignore files (`gitignore_global.txt`).  If you are working on a Windows machine (which I assume you are), you might want to check in My Documents.  If you have SourceTree installed, check in Atlassian's program files as well.  More than likely, you will see that `*.dll` is in these files.  Remove that, and you should be good.

Now, I know the big thing is that you shouldn't include DLLs in your git repository.  Every point that Cupcake makes is valid.  However, in reality, the size concern really only applies to **frequently-changing** DLLs.  Since the DLLs in `obj` and `bin` folders throughout your solution change on almost every single build, those would be a nightmare in size for git.  However, your package repositories change relatively infrequently.  And even at a high edge case, they are not that much of a threat: if you have 20 packages, each with a 100KB DLL, and each package has run 10 updates, that brings you to 20MB total of that 1GB limit - 2%.  Conversely, if you decide not to include the DLLs, as Cupcake and many others would say is required, then that means you have to deal with one of two consequences:

1. Your repository will not build on checkout
2. You must use the nuget package restore - which sounds great, but essentially means you are reinstalling the packages on every single checkout.  It might potentially be every single build, but more than likely only on the first build after checkout.

Neither of these consequences seem acceptable.  Furthermore, Nuget Package Restore is not immediately configurable for easily updating packages through Visual Studio, even though the built-in package manager for VS makes this incredibly simple.  Letting git find the DLLs not in `bin` and `obj` and adding them naturally means you can update packages via NuGet in Visual Studio, git will find those new packages, remove the old packages, and your solution builds on checkout.

The side effect of this is very important: it means that you MUST make sure that your repository (and every repository cloned onto your machine) must include `bin` and `obj` in their repository-level `.gitignore`.  If you do not do this, then those frequently-changing DLLs will come into your repo and they will eat up a large amount of space, in all likelihood.  The flipside is that there is so much in those folders that you should be ignoring already - debug packages, etc. - that you are hopefully doing this already anyway.  In fact, many pre-configured `.gitignore` files you find for .NET/Windows projects already include ignores for those folders.

In the end, while the principle of not including DLLs in your git repository is good, you cannot forget that it is most important for **frequently-changing** DLLs, and that your dependencies should most certainly be included with your project for consistency, ease-of-build, and efficiency.